# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function Module.<anonymous>

Tags: reactjs

I am getting error when using `reactReduxFirebase(fbConfig)` . and I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with the code. If I'm wrong, please let me know.

[Error Description image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIZ13.png)

**Dependencies:**

```
"firebase": "^8.9.1",
"react": "^17.0.2",    
"react-redux": "^7.2.4",
"react-redux-firebase": "^3.10.0",    
"redux": "^4.1.1",
"redux-firestore": "^0.15.0",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
"vs": "^0.1.0"
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

import {createStore,applyMiddleware,compose} from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './store/reducers/rootReducer';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {createFirestoreInstance, reduxFirestore,getFirestore} from 'redux-firestore';
import {ReactReduxFirebaseProvider,reactReduxFirebase,getFirebase} from 'react-redux-firebase';
import fbConfig from './config/fbConfig';
import firebase from 'firebase/app'

let store=createStore(rootReducer,compose(
  applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({getFirestore,getFirebase})),
  reduxFirestore(fbConfig),
  //reactReduxFirebase(fbConfig)
));


// ReactDOM.render(
//   <Provider store={store}>
//     <React.StrictMode>
//       <App />
//     </React.StrictMode>
//   </Provider>,
//   document.getElementById('root')
// );

const rrfProps = {
  firebase,
  config: fbConfig,
  dispatch: store.dispatch,
  createFirestoreInstance
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
    <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider{...rrfProps}>
        <App />
      </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
      </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
reportWebVitals();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check firebase and config params again.
it seems you are passing wrong values.
https://prnt.sc/1q1hejy

// firebase config ex. firebaseConfig.js

```
    import * as firebase from 'firebase';
    import 'firebase/auth';
    import 'firebase/firestore';
    import 'firebase/functions';
    
    const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: 'XXXXX',
        authDomain: 'XXXX',
        databaseURL: 'XXXX',
        projectId: 'XXXX',
        storageBucket: 'XXXX',
        messagingSenderId: 'XXXX',
        appId: 'XXXX',
        measurementId: 'XXXX',
    };
    
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    firebase.firestore();
    firebase.functions();
    
    export default firebase;
```

firebase must be from firebaseConfig.js

```
    import firebase from './firebaseConfig.js'

    ....
    const rrfConfig = {
        userProfile: 'users', // user collection
        useFirestoreForProfile: true, // to use firestore instance
    };
    const rrfProps = {
        firebase,
        config: rrfConfig,
        dispatch: store.dispatch,
        createFirestoreInstance: createFirestoreInstance,
    };
    ...
    ...
    
    <Provider store={store}>
         <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>
             <App />
         </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
    </Provider>
    
    ...
```

- please make sure you created realtime database.

Comment: Now I am using the below code. And downgraded to "react-redux and react-redux-firebase" version then it is working properly.
 "react-redux": "^5.1.1", "react-redux-firebase": "^2.2.4",
https://prnt.sc/1q1o2i8

Comment: Okay, it also should work , but only for the old version. :) My code is for latest version. "react-redux" ^7.2.4, "react-redux-firestore" ^3.10.0

Comment: Please provide the solution without changing the version. and do not affect other functionality